# Как сравнить два списка используя метод Set?

Tags: swift

Здравствуйте. Я новичок в использований метода Set, есть старый список `var old_collection_Comment = [Data_Collection_Comment]()`, который содержится в виде словаря

```
class Data_Collection_Comment {

    var avatar_user : String
    var publication_id : String
    var id_comment : String
    var user_fio : String
    var massage_comment : String

    init(avatar_user : String, user_fio : String, id_comment : String,  massage_comment : String, publication_id: String) {

        self.avatar_user = avatar_user
        self.id_comment = id_comment
        self.publication_id = publication_id
        self.user_fio = user_fio
        self.massage_comment = massage_comment
    }
}
```

Делаю запрос на получение данных `let result = API().API_POST_Parametres(url_Api: (self?.data_Dictionary.url["get_publication_comment"]!)!, parametres: parameters)` В ответе при запросе возвращаю `NSArray`, вот ссылка на данные https://pastebin.com/8PtmBcFF

Comment: под `метод Set` вы имеете в виду коллекцию Set (множество) или действительно какой-то свой метод Set?

Answer (score 0):

Формируете 2 Set. Один Set будет содержать id старых комментариев. Второй Set будет содержать id всех комментариев пришедших в ответе с сервера.

```
let oldSet: Set = [1, 4, 3, 6]
let newSet: Set = [1, 4, 3, 6, 2, 8, 12]

let resultSet = oldSet.union(newSet)
// [1, 4, 3, 6, 2, 8, 12]       

let resultSet2 = oldSet.intersection(newSet)
// [6, 4, 1, 3]

let resultSet3 = oldSet.symmetricDifference(newSet)
// [12, 2, 8]
```